# Family critical of my Come Dine with Me scoring system.

Tags: scoring-algorithm

My family and I have been arguing for years about a fun 'Come Dine with Me' competition we held between the six of us.

If you're not familiar with the show, a group of people all host a dinner party, and the remaining group members give the night a score out of 10. After everybody has hosted their dinner party, the scores are added up and a winner (and order of losers) is determined.

Before we started, I told everybody that, no matter how good the first dinner party was, I would be scoring it a 5. My argument for this was that it gave me the maximum amount of room (thereabouts) to base the subsequent scores relative to this first score.

If the first party was great, I didn't want to give it a 10, because of the next one was better then I'd have nowhere to go.

Since the game was completely self-contained (e.g. we weren't using the winner's score to compete against another family) then my argument is that the winner and order of loses would remain exactly the same.

My family didn't accept this and said I wasn't being fair and that this scoring system wasn't in the spirit of the game. We ended up cancelling the entire game after the first night and we've argued about it ever since. This happened around seven years ago.

My family and I are far from being mathematics scholars, so I wondered if people could confirm, in layman's terms, whether I was right. And perhaps someone could explain *why* I'm right better than I can :)

Comment: Formerly, top-level amateur figure skating had a scoring system that prevented this problem. Judges would give each skater's performance two scores between 0.0 and 6.0.  But these raw scores were never used directly.  Instead they were converted to lists: for each judge there was a list of which skater they liked best, which next-best, and so on.  An algorithm then selected the winners based on their positions in the preference lists. Judges were therefore free to assign whatever meaning they liked to the original six-point scores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fair only if
a) everyone else ranks the first party as a $5$ too, or
b) you don't take part in the competion (that is, you never host a party - you act merely as a judge for everyone else's parties, in which case it's is fair for all of them).

Here's the reasoning for why your system  is unfair:

Say all the parties were equally good, but "objectively" better than a $5/10$, say $8/10$.

Then, you would receive $8 \times 5 = 40$ overall points. However, everyone else would receive $8 \times 4 + 5 = 37$ points ($5$ from you, because you're comparing to the first party, and $8$ from everyone else). So, you would unfairly win in spite of the fact that everyone hosted equally good parties.

a) is fair for everyone, because once the first party gets $5 \times 5 = 25$ points, everyone rates all following parties using $5$ as a guideline, so all points for all the remaining parties are equally offset. That is, comparing to $25$ becomes fair.

b) is fair for everyone (assuming you don't take part), because you're not in the system, so you just act like an 'external judge' that differentiates between everyone else in your family.

I think the way to go forward for next time is for everyone to give their points *at the end of all parties*, giving what they think is the best party a 10. This solves both issues - everyone will have 'room to judge to other parties' and because everyone ranks the best party at 10, there won't be any unfair offset.

Comment: Great answer and really well explained. Thank you! I'm wrong, but at least I know why :)

Comment: It is not enough to give the best dinner a 10, the worst has to be given a 0

Comment: Yes, cause we're assuming people "judge parties" linearly. So, we need to specify two points. Should I edit my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the scale has a maximum of 10. This implies that the numbers 1 to 10 are evenly divided from bad to perfect, making a 5 out of 10 very poor. By using such a scale you already have two reference points, 1 and 10, with which to compare the quality, and adding a third reference point (5 for the first meal) would make the scale non-linear.

Here are three ways to deal with the problem.

1. Use a scale without a maximum. The first meal is given a default score, of say 100, and all other meals are judged relative to that (and to the zero score). Unfortunately this does not work well with multiple judges, as each will essentially have their own scale (based on how good they felt the first meal was). You would have to normalise each scale (e.g. divide by the maximum score) before averaging the judges' scores.
2. Use a finer grained scale. If the first meal was very good, give it for example an 8.5 which still gives you enough slots above it to place every meal to come.
3. Accept that you cannot differentiate between every meal, and that you will have to give some meals the same scores. It is not your job to rank them, it is your job to score them. The ranking only comes after the scores of all the judges have been averaged, resulting in a more precise score.

Comment: Surely, approach 2 has the same problem as in the original case? And approach 3 doesn't really solve the issue of 'leaving enough room', which is the kind of system we are looking for, right?

Comment: @GlobeTheatre: #2 has the same problem only if you score it a 10. Nevertheless you can still score it fairly, even giving it a 9.9 and still be able to give a later meals a higher score such as 9.94, 9.96 or 9.99. As for #3, I said "deal with" rather than "solve". The point I was making is that you don't have to worry about having enough slots if you accept that each slot may be used more than once.

Comment: Ah okay, I see what you mean now